# How to define a prediction function in keras for NER system?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, named-entity-recognition

I am creating a NER system following some tutorials using Keras. After the training and the first prediction, I'd like to use it to identify the NEs in a single string or in a list of strings of unseen data.

I can't seem to find the way to pass such string, or list of strings to the `model.predict()` and get an appropriate prediction.

This is the prediction for the test data in my code, so I was trying to adjust it to accept strings of unseen data and print the token + prediction:

```
i = np.random.randint(0, x_test.shape[0])
print("This is sentence:",i)
p = model.predict(np.array([x_test[i]]))
p = np.argmax(p, axis=-1)

print("{:15}{:5}\t {}\n".format("Word", "True", "Pred"))
print("-" *30)
for w, true, pred in zip(x_test[i], y_test[i], p[0]):
    print("{:15}{}\t{}".format(words[w-1], tags[true], tags[pred]))
```

This piece of code predicts and print each token with the NE Tag, but I don't really understand how it works

This code prints something like:

```
Word           True      Pred
------------------------------
The            O        O
British        B-gpe    B-gpe
pharmaceutical O        O
company        O        O
GlaxoSmithKlineB-org    O
```

I'd like to pass for example:

```
sentence = "President Obama became the first sitting American president to visit Hiroshima"
```

and being able to see the identified NEs. Any advise on how to do this?

A copy of the full code is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Nc8U3B6K1NRthLixWEceoggjmFPi99cM?usp=sharing) and the dataset is used is [here](https://www.kaggle.com/abhinavwalia95/entity-annotated-corpus/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a prediction on a list of sentences like this:

```
my_sentences = ["President Obama became the first sitting American president to visit Hiroshima",
                "Jack is a good person and living in Iran"]

my_sentences_idx = [[word2idx[w] for w in s.split(" ")] for s in my_sentences]

my_sentences_padded = pad_sequences(maxlen=max_len, sequences=my_sentences_idx, padding="post", value=num_words-1)
preds = np.argmax(model.predict(np.array(my_sentences_padded)), axis=-1)

for idx, p in enumerate(preds):
    print("-" *30)
    print(my_sentences[idx])
    print("-" *30)
    for w, pred in zip(my_sentences[idx].split(" "), preds[idx]):
        if tags[pred]!="O":
            print("{:15} {} ".format(w, tags[pred]))
    print()
```

Output:

```
------------------------------
President Obama became the first sitting American president to visit Hiroshima
------------------------------
President       B-per 
Obama           I-per 
American        B-gpe 
Hiroshima       B-geo 

------------------------------
Jack is a good person and living in Iran
------------------------------
Jack            B-per 
Iran            B-geo
```

Comment: When trying to run your code I get the following error: 
KeyError: 'President'. 
I will add it as an answer to the question as comments won't let me format it correctly.

Comment: @StivenLancheros: Don't add it as answer. Edit your question. It is because `President` word is not in your  `word2idx` dictionary. I ran your code, and it returned no error with the above sentences. I recommend once again run your code from first cell in order. You may somewhere amended the `word2idx` variable.